# tricky interesting algebra question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

If $(7^x − 7^{−x}) / (7^x − 7^{−x}) = y$ then $x =??$.

I do not understand the question. How can we solve and continue with it if it all equals one?

Comment: You can't.  Where is the problem from?  You can say $y=1$ unless $x=0$ (in which case the fraction is not defined)

Comment: question number 29 http://www.ucl.ac.uk/clie/placement-tests/UPC/complete.php?exercise=Maths-2

Comment: You must say : $x\neq.?$

Answer (score 3):

I suspect they have a typo and the intended question is $$(7^x − 7^{−x}) / (7^x + 7^{−x}) = y$$
Looking at the answers you are supposed to invert the equation by multiplying top and bottom by $7^x,$ solve for $7^x$ and take the base $7$ log to get $x$